# My WordPress website with a ReactJs pluggin isn't getting properly indexed by Google

Tags: html, reactjs, wordpress, indexing, seo

I'm handling the SEO for a client's website, but there's an issue with indexing. The developer used a ReactJs plugin to populate the H1 tags, title, and tables on the website. The title includes date and time information. However, I've observed that Google isn't indexing the content correctly.

Due to the ReactJs plugin used within WordPress, there's a delay in downloading the content, impacting the indexing process. The website is 4 months.

What steps can be taken to resolve this problem?

I attempted to reduce the loading time of the ReactJS application by employing various techniques, including compression using tools like UglifyJS.

Comment: A web page structured as you describe is hard to index because the spider robot program at Google has to run the javascript to retrieve the page's useful content. Sites with this kind of page absolutely need a good site map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered a similar scenario with a client who used a ReactJs plugin to populate charts, titles, and table data. They eventually had to switch from the ReactJs plugin to a PHP plugin. Following the conversion, the data now loads within milliseconds. Here is my client website.

https://goldrateinqatar.com

It's crucial to note that Google favors websites with excellent performance. You can utilize the [Google PageSpeed](https://pagespeed.web.dev/) tool to assess and improve website performance. Performance of a website is directly proportion to indexing.